# Delovaya kolbasa

Tags: сленг

What does "delovaya kolbasa" mean in Russian?

Comment: this could be a translation request, but it just as well could be a request for explanation of a slang phrase meaning

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I agree

Comment: Related question: [Предложить деловую колбасу...](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83-should-be-served-on-business-occasions-to-show-resp)

Answer (score 4):

It is **"delavaya kalbasa"** literally **`a busy sausage`**

The [Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0) tells it's an ironic designation for a person who's always busy with something, who's demonstrably busy, the Web indicates that it could also be a businessman/woman.

[image]

Comment: I'd correct you proposing this variant:  `business sausage`. :)

Answer (score 3):

While the answer provided is absolutely correct, it's not necessarily about somebody being pretentiously busy. "Деловая колбаса" can be applicable in many circumstances and is a rough equivalent of "you are such a clever/smart guy/ass" said ironically.

For instance, a daughter can suggest to her father to leave her all the candies in exchange for butter and her father can say: "Ну ты и деловая колбаса".